# EF Code First relations and associative entity

Tags: entity-framework

So I need to have User, Companies and Channels.

User:

- is tied to one Company

Channel:

- is tied to one Company
- can have many users

Company:

- can have many users
- can have many channels

```
public class User {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Channel> Channels { get; set; }
}

public class Company {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Channel> Channels { get; set; }
}

public class Channel {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyUser {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    
    public long CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public bool IsOwner { get; set; }
    public bool ChannelLimit { get; set; }
}

public class ChannelUser {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    
    public long ChannelId { get; set; }
    public virtual Channel Channel { get; set; }

    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public bool IsOwner { get; set; }
}
```

How to make this efficient and working? What's the way to handle all relations?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a number of many-to-many relationships where 1-to-many would suffice:

User is tied to one Company

Channel is tied to one Company, can have many users

Company can have many users, can have many channels

```
public class User
{
    [Key] 
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual Channel Channel { get; set; }
}

public class Channel
{
    [Key]
    public int ChannelId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; } = new List<User>();
}

public class Company
{
    [Key]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Channel> Channels { get; set; } = new List<Channel>();
}
```

When mapped, the company mapping will have a `HasMany(x => x.Channels).WithRequired(x => x.Company);`
The channel mapping will have a `HasMany(x => x.Users).WithOptional();`

To get Users for a company you can go through Channels:

```
var companyUsers = context.Companies
    .Where(c => c.CompanyId == companyId)
    .SelectMany(c => c.Channels.SelectMany(ch => ch.Users))
    .ToList();
```

That being a very basic example to get all users associated with a single company. When reading company and related channel/user info you can dive through the association to select and filter the details as desired.

Just as with DB design, it is usually advisable to keep entity relationships relatively normalized to avoid references to each other scattered everywhere. EF does a great job of building queries to pull data through the navigation properties where needed.

Edit: Ok, users can create a channel, potentially creating multiple channels and assuming from the earlier description multiple other users can be assigned to the channel. Channels are also potentially "owned" by one company.

Take 2:
public class User
{
[Key]
public int UserId { get; internal set; }
public virtual Company Company { get; internal set; } // optional

```
    public virtual ICollection<ChannelUser> ChannelUsers { get; internal set; } = new List<ChannelUser>();

    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<Channel> Channels
    {
       get { return ChannelUsers.Select(x => x.Channel).ToList(); }
    }
    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<Channel> OwnedChannels
    {
       get { return ChannelUsers.Where(x => x.IsOwned).Select(x => x.Channel).ToList(); }
    }    
}

public class Channel
{
    [Key]
    public int ChannelId { get; internal set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ChannelUser> ChannelUsers { get; internal set; } = new List<ChannelUser>();
    public virtual ICollection<ChannelCompany> ChannelCompanies { get; internal set; } = new List<ChannelCompany>();

    [NotMapped]
    public User OwnerUser
    {
        get { return ChannelUsers.SingleOrDefault(x => x.IsOwner)?.User; }
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public User OwnerCompany
    {
        get { return ChannelCompanies.SingleOrDefault(x => x.IsOwner)?.Company; }
    }

}

public class Company
{
    [Key]
    public int CompanyId { get; internal set; }
}

public class ChannelUser
{
    public int ChannelId { get; internal set; }
    public int UserId { get; internal set; }
    public bool IsOwner { get; internal set; }
    public virtual Channel Channel { get; internal set; }
    public virtual User User { get; internal set; }
}

public class ChannelCompany
{
    public int ChannelId { get; internal set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; internal set; }
    public bool IsOwner { get; internal set; }
    public virtual Channel Channel { get; internal set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; internal set; }
}
```

This maps similar to your original with many-to-many relationships between Channel and User and Company. The concept of an "owner" would be on the joining tables. I added some unmapped helper properties to make it easier for code using the entities to navigate through the linking entities. Be warned though that these properties cannot be used in EF Linq expressions. For instance when writing Linq queries against the dbSets and navigation properties you will need to use the linking entity collections because EF won't be able to resolve the unmapped ones. EF6 & EF Core 3+ will throw exceptions if you try to use them in a query, EF Core 2 would generate a warning and auto-materialize the query into memory which is a potentially huge performance/memory sink.

The trouble with models like this is that they can get the job done, but will rely on your code logic to enforce that the rules around expected relationships between channels, users, and companies are enforced. For instance, expecting that every channel has 1, and only 1 owning user (if required) and 0 or 1 owning company. (if optional)

To do this, I would recommend using Actions (methods) on the entities to modify state rather than accessing setters/collections directly. For example, if you can create a channel for a user, have a CreateChannel() method on user with the required parameters:

```
public Channel CreateChannel(string name /* , other required fields */)
{
    var channel = new Channel
    {
        Name = name,
        //...
    };
    var channelUser new ChannelUser { Channel = channel, User = this, IsOwner = true });
    ChannelUsers.Add(channelUser);
    channel.ChannelUsers.Add(channelUser);
    return channel;
}
```

This assumes that the DbContext that read the associated User entity is in-scope and alive when `user.CreateChannel()` is called, and `SaveChanges()` is called afterwards. For instance, somewhere in a controller action to create a Channel from data provided in the Post:

```
using (var context = new AppContext())
{
    var user = context.Users.Single(x => x.UserId == userId);
    var channel = user.CreateChannel(channelName /*, .... */);
    context.SaveChanges();
    // Potentially return view information for the newly created Channel...
}
```

Changing a channel owner between users (whether limited to user already associated to the channel or a new user) can be contained in a method on Channel to update the appropriate collections in one operation to ensure the IsOwner state is kept valid. This is where I will make setters `internal` to discourage attempting to mutate state with setters instead of using action methods.

Anyhow, this should hopefully give you a few things to think about. Ultimately look to narrow down the allowed relationships to the minimum viable connection points between the entities. Many-to-many relationships can complicate things in terms of enforcing valid combinations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I see how that would make sense, but there are some infos still missing that I need. User could have (create) multiple channels and I need to know who is the owner of that channel (who added it) same with the Company, I need to know which user is the owner. I think I screwed up a bit in my question. User belongs to one company (but it's not required, it could be a "freelancer"), can have many channels. Channel belongs to one company and can have many users in it. Company can have many users and many channels.

Comment: Ok, I've expanded my answer to hopefully give you a few ideas on something to try to help organize those relationships.